# Why did I receive 2 rep for getting upvote on my answer? 

Tags: support, status-norepro, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I am sure there is something wrong with Stack Overflow reputation system today, please check my previous Meta question: [Really I earned 200 reputation yesterday?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118116/really-i-earned-200-reputation-yesterday) .

Now, one more weird problem I came across, I got 2 rep points for having upvote on my answer, yes I have given this answer. I know that we get 2 rep points for accepting answer of other user but here I got for having upvote on my own answer.

Now here is [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307090/how-to-add-background-image-to-activity/3307191#3307191) for which I got 2 rep points, instead it should be 10 points I think.

[image]

Update:

---

At this time (Indian 6:44PM 6 jan 2012), I came across this situation, 2 rep points with question is not being displayed, actually 2 rep points is not added in my total reps, but my question 2 rep points is showing for what reason?

[image]

Comment: You hit the rep cap (200 points). You must have had a down-vote (or given at least 2 down-votes) so only the part of the last up-vote needed to get you back to 200 was allocated.

Comment: But question is why only 2 rep points received for my answer and i got 2 rep points down for my questions? Why 2 rep points instead of 10/5 rep points for upvote and downvote?

Comment: Because 198 + 10 = 208 which is 8 points over the cap. Therefore you only get two points 198 + 2 = 200 .

Comment: Your question has been answered: You only had 2 points to go to hit the cap of 200, so that's all you could earn.

Comment: -2 is what you get when someone down votes one of your answers. It's not -10

Comment: @JNK'sMetAccount my dear my mind is actually banged just because today i was seeing different cases of reputation. I know about reputation system fully. And i haven't seen this case of +2 if i cross reputation cap points.

Comment: @PareshMayani - if you knew about it fully then you would know what the rep cap was.  You would also not be confused by -2 for a downvote.

Comment: @JNK'sMetAccount yes i only knew if we got 200 points in a day then its reputation cap, not knowing more than it.

Comment: @JNK'sMetAccount just check this another question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118116/really-i-earned-200-reputation-yesterday

Comment: @PareshMayani - thats about a minor bug in the heading in one of the tabs, not the actual rep calculation.  This is not instilling confidence.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You had a downvote before - the upvote ended up rounding up to the 200 rep cap.

[image]

Comment: yes you are right, but why 2 rep points instead of 10 rep points for upvote/downvote? i agree it becomes 2-2=0 but why its 2 actually?

Comment: @PareshMayani You were at the reputation cap (200).  Someone downvoted one of your answers (-2).  Someone upvoted one of your answers (normally +10, but you can only earn +2 now because of the cap, so you get +2).  RAWR.

Comment: @Paresh You lost 2 points because someone down voted you. That's how much you lose from being down voted on an answer... not 10. So that left you 2 shy of the cap.